# How to join values between sublists

Tags: python

I have a list with sublists, for example:

```
LA=[[1,2],[2,7],[4,5],[1,9],[6,5],[4,3],[2,1],[2,2]]
```

If the first element in each sublist is an ID, how do I join the ones with the same ID to get something like this:

```
LR=[[1,11],[2,10],[4,8],[6,5]]
```

I've tried using a `for` loop, but it's too long and not efficient.

Comment: This sounds like a job for a `dict` summation.  Search for how to accumulate values in a `dict`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Show your own code and explain "join the ones with the same ID". Do you mean adding values together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping with [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is always straightforward:

```
from collections import defaultdict

LA = [[1,2],[2,7],[4,5],[1,9],[6,5],[4,3],[2,1],[2,2]]

# create defaultdict of list values
d = defaultdict(list)

# loop over each list
for sublist in LA:

    # group by first element of each list
    key = sublist[0]

    # add to dictionary, each key will have a list of values
    d[key].append(sublist)

# definitely can be more readable
result = [[key, sum(x[1] for x in [y for y in value])] for (key, value) in sorted(d.items())]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 11], [2, 10], [4, 8], [6, 5]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
LA=[[1,2],[2,7],[4,5],[1,9],[6,5],[4,3],[2,1],[2,2]]
new_d = [[a, sum(i[-1] for i in list(b))] for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(LA), key=lambda x:x[0])]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 11], [2, 10], [4, 8], [6, 5]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
LA=[[1,2],[2,7],[4,5],[1,9],[6,5],[4,3],[2,1],[2,2]]

new_dict = {}
for (key, value) in LA:
    if key in new_dict:
        new_dict[key].append(value)
    else:
        new_dict[key] = [value]


for key, value in new_dict.items():

    new_dict[key] = (sum(value))

dictlist = []

for key, value in new_dict.items():
    temp = [key,value]
    dictlist.append(temp)

print(dictlist)
```

will do the job too

Answer (score 2):

You can do it just using list comprehensions:

```
LR = [[i,sum([L[1] for L in LA if L[0]==i])] for i in set([L[0] for L in LA])]
```

Gives the desired result.

To break this down a bit `set([L[0] for L in LA])` gives a set (with no repeats) of all of the ID's, then we simply itterate over that set and sum the values which also have that ID.